# How to fix "Cannot read property 'setAttribute' of undefined"

Tags: javascript, setattribute

I'm trying to create a code to show 5 buttons categories and the slider of the last products below. On mouseover effect on any category I'm expecting to see the relevant products of woocommerce. But it doesn't work: neither the buttons nor the product slider. I have an error in console "Cannot read property 'setAttribute' of undefined". How can it possible to solve the problem?

```js
var carouseltopHtml = [];

jQuery(function($) {
  var touchtimea = 0;
  var touchtimeb = 0;
  var touchtimec = 0;
  var touchtimed = 0;
  var touchtimee = 0;
  $("#top_a_category_0").on("click", function() {
    if (touchtimea == 0) {
      onmuseoverslider(0);
      touchtimea = new Date().getTime();
      touchtimeb = 0;
      touchtimec = 0;
      touchtimed = 0;
      touchtimee = 0;
      if (window.innerWidth < 1024) {
        return false;
      }
    } else {
      // compare first click to this click and see if they occurred within double click threshold
      if (((new Date().getTime()) - touchtimea) < 3000) {
        window.location = this.href;
        touchtimea = 0;
      } else {
        // not a double click so set as a new first click
        touchtimea = new Date().getTime();
        return false;
      }
    }
  });
  $("#top_a_category_1").on("click", function() {
    if (touchtimeb == 0) {
      onmuseoverslider(1);
      touchtimeb = new Date().getTime();
      touchtimea = 0;
      touchtimec = 0;
      touchtimed = 0;
      touchtimee = 0;
      if (window.innerWidth < 1024) {
        return false;
      }
    } else {
      // compare first click to this click and see if they occurred within double click threshold
      if (((new Date().getTime()) - touchtimeb) < 3000) {
        window.location = this.href;
        touchtimeb = 0;
      } else {
        // not a double click so set as a new first click
        touchtimeb = new Date().getTime();
        return false;
      }
    }
  });
  $("#top_a_category_2").on("click", function() {
    if (touchtimec == 0) {
      onmuseoverslider(2);
      touchtimea = 0;
      touchtimeb = 0;
      touchtimed = 0;
      touchtimee = 0;
      touchtimec = new Date().getTime();
      if (window.innerWidth < 1024) {
        return false;
      }
    } else {
      // compare first click to this click and see if they occurred within double click threshold
      if (((new Date().getTime()) - touchtimec) < 3000) {
        window.location = this.href;
        touchtimec = 0;
      } else {
        // not a double click so set as a new first click
        touchtimec = new Date().getTime();
        return false;
      }
    }
  });
  $("#top_a_category_3").on("click", function() {
    if (touchtimed == 0) {
      onmuseoverslider(3);
      touchtimed = new Date().getTime();
      touchtimea = 0;
      touchtimeb = 0;
      touchtimec = 0;
      touchtimee = 0;
      if (window.innerWidth < 1024) {
        return false;
      }
    } else {
      // compare first click to this click and see if they occurred within double click threshold
      if (((new Date().getTime()) - touchtimed) < 3000) {
        window.location = this.href;
        touchtimed = 0;
      } else {
        // not a double click so set as a new first click
        touchtimed = new Date().getTime();
        return false;
      }
    }
  });
  $("#top_a_category_4").on("click", function() {
    if (touchtimee == 0) {
      onmuseoverslider(4);
      touchtimee = new Date().getTime();
      touchtimea = 0;
      touchtimeb = 0;
      touchtimec = 0;
      touchtimed = 0;
      if (window.innerWidth < 1024) {
        return false;
      }
    } else {
      // compare first click to this click and see if they occurred within double click threshold
      if (((new Date().getTime()) - touchtimee) < 800) {
        window.location = this.href;
        touchtimee = 0;
      } else {
        // not a double click so set as a new first click
        touchtimee = new Date().getTime();
        return false;
      }
    }
  });

});
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
  for (var i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
    carouseltopHtml[i] = jQuery("#carrou0" + i).html();
    if (i > 0) {
      jQuery("#carrou0" + i).html('');
    }
    //jQuery("#carrou_bottom_" + i ).css('display','none');
  }
});
for (var j = 0; j < 5; j++) {
  if (window.innerWidth < 1024) {
    if (j == 2)
      document.getElementById('top_nav_category_' + j).setAttribute("style", "width:100%; height: 50px; min-height: 50px; background-image: url(); margin-bottom:0px");
    else
      document.getElementById('top_nav_category_' + j).setAttribute("style", "width:80%; height: fit-content; min-height: 50px; background-image: url(); margin-bottom:0px");
    document.getElementById('top_a_category_' + j).setAttribute("style", "display: contents; margin-top: 0px; text-align: center;");
  }
}

function onmuseoverslider(id) {
  for (var i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
    if (id == i)
      jQuery("#carrou0" + i).html(carouseltopHtml[i]);
    //jQuery("#carrou_bottom_" + i ).css('display','block');
    else
      jQuery("#carrou0" + i).html('');
    // jQuery("#carrou_bottom_" + i ).css('display','none');

  }
  loadtopslider(id + 1);
  /*for(var i = 1; i < 6; i ++){
   if(i == id)
    document.getElementById('carrou0'+id).className += ' mostrar';
   else
    document.getElementById('carrou0'+i).className =document.getElementById('carrou0'+i).className.replace(/(?:^|\s)mostrar(?!\S)/g,'');
  }*/
}

function loadtopslider(index) {
  //jQuery( '.wcpscwc-product-slider' ).each(function( index ) {
  var item = jQuery('.wcpscwc-product-slider')[0];
  var slider_id = jQuery(item).attr('id');
  var slider_conf = jQuery.parseJSON(jQuery(item).closest('.wcpscwc-product-slider-wrap').find('.wcpscwc-slider-conf').attr('data-conf'));
  var slider_cls = slider_conf.slider_cls ? slider_conf.slider_cls : 'products';

  jQuery('#' + slider_id + ' .' + slider_cls).not('.slick-initialized').slick({
    dots: (slider_conf.dots) == "true" ? true : false,
    infinite: true,
    arrows: (slider_conf.arrows) == "true" ? true : false,
    speed: parseInt(slider_conf.speed),
    autoplay: (slider_conf.autoplay) == "true" ? true : false,
    autoplaySpeed: parseInt(slider_conf.autoplay_speed),
    slidesToShow: parseInt(slider_conf.slide_to_show),
    slidesToScroll: parseInt(slider_conf.slide_to_scroll),
    rtl: (slider_conf.rtl) == "true" ? true : false,
    responsive: [{
        breakpoint: 1023,
        settings: {
          slidesToShow: 3,
          slidesToScroll: 1,
          infinite: true,
          dots: false
        }
      }, {

        breakpoint: 767,
        settings: {
          slidesToShow: 2,
          slidesToScroll: 1
        }
      },
      {
        breakpoint: 479,
        settings: {
          slidesToShow: 1,
          slidesToScroll: 1,
          dots: false
        }
      },
      {
        breakpoint: 319,
        settings: {
          slidesToShow: 1,
          slidesToScroll: 1,
          dots: false
        }
      }
    ]
  });
  //});
}
```

```css
.btnstop:hover,
.btnstop:focus {
  background-color: #ebebeb;
  transform: scale(1.1);
  box-shadow: 2px 1px 2px 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="carouselcattop01">
  <ul class="ulbtncatcar">
    <li class="btncatcar01 btnstop" id="top_nav_category_0" onmouseover="onmuseoverslider(0)" style="width: 15%; height: 20%;">
      <a href="/categorie-produit/les-rouges/" title="Vins Rouges" class="titre" title="Les vins rouges" id="top_a_category_0">
        <h3 style="color: #000000; font-size: 2vw; margin-bottom: 0px; font-family: Prata; ">Vins</h3>
        <h2 style="color: #025F6D; font-family: Montserrat; font-size: 1.5vw;"> Rouges</h2>
      </a>

    </li>
    <li class="btncatcar02 btnstop" id="top_nav_category_1" onmouseover="onmuseoverslider(1)" style="width: 15%; height: 20%;">
      <a href="/categorie-produit/les-roses/" title="Vins Rosés" class="titre" title="Les vins rosés" id="top_a_category_1">
        <h3 style="color: #000000; font-size: 2vw; margin-bottom: 0px; font-family: Prata;">Vins</h3>
        <h2 style="color: #0092A7; font-family: Montserrat; font-size: 1.5vw; margin-bottom: 0px;"> Rosés</h2>
      </a>

    </li>
    <li class="btncatcar03 btnstop" id="top_nav_category_2" onmouseover="onmuseoverslider(2)" style="width: 15%; height: 20%;">
      <a href="/categorie-produit/les-blanc-liquoreux-et-secs/" title="Vins Blancs Secs et Liquoreux" class="titre" title="Les vins blancs" id="top_a_category_2">
        <h3 style="color: #000000; font-size: 2vw; margin-bottom: 0px; font-family: Prata; padding-top: 10px;">Vins</h3>
        <h2 style="color: #0092A7; font-family: Montserrat; font-size: 1.5vw;"> Blancs</h2>
        <h5 style="color: #0092A7; font-family: Montserrat; font-size: 1vw;"> Secs et Liquoreux</h5>
      </a>

    </li>
    <li class="btncatcar04 btnstop" id="top_nav_category_3" onmouseover="onmuseoverslider(3)" style="width: 15%; height: 20%;">
      <a href="/categorie-produit/les-bulles/" title="Vins Pétillants" class="titre" title="Les vins pétillants" id="top_a_category_3">
        <h3 style="color: #000000; font-size: 2vw; margin-bottom: 0px; font-family: Prata;">Vins</h3>
        <h2 style="color: #9BD0D9; font-family: Montserrat; font-size: 1.5vw;"> Pétillants</h2>
      </a>

    </li>
    <li class="btncatcar05 btnstop" id="top_nav_category_4" onmouseover="onmuseoverslider(4)" style="width: 15%; height: 20%;">
      <a href="/categorie-produit/idees-cadeaux/" title="Idées Cadeaux" class="titre" title="Les idées cadeaux" id="top_a_category_4">
        <h3 style="color: #000000; font-size: 2vw; margin-bottom: 0px; font-family: Prata;">Idées</h3>
        <h2 style="color: #B1B3B4; font-family: Montserrat; font-size: 1.5vw;"> Cadeaux</h2>
      </a>

    </li>
    <ul id="carrou00" class="ulcarrousel ocultar mostrar">
      <li class="licarrousel">
        <div class="dudomaine">Les <strong>vins rouges</strong> du Domaine</div>
        [products_slider cats="21" slide_to_show="5" design="design-5" dots="false" slide_to_scroll="2"]
      </li>
    </ul>
    <ul id="carrou01" class="ulcarrousel ocultar mostrar">
      <li class="licarrousel">
        <div class="dudomaine">Les <strong>vins rosés</strong> du Domaine</div>
        [products_slider cats="22" slide_to_show="5" design="design-5" dots="false" slide_to_scroll="2"]
      </li>
    </ul>
    <ul id="carrou02" class="ulcarrousel ocultar mostrar">
      <li class="licarrousel">
        <div class="dudomaine">Les <strong>vins blancs</strong> du Domaine</div>
        [products_slider cats="23" slide_to_show="5" design="design-5" dots="false" slide_to_scroll="2"]
      </li>
    </ul>
    <ul id="carrou03" class="ulcarrousel ocultar mostrar">
      <li class="licarrousel">
        <div class="dudomaine">Les <strong>vins pétillants</strong> du Domaine</div>
        [products_slider cats="24" slide_to_show="5" design="design-5" dots="false" slide_to_scroll="2"]
      </li>
    </ul>
    <ul id="carrou04" class="ulcarrousel ocultar mostrar">
      <li class="licarrousel">
        <div class="dudomaine">Les <strong>idées cadeaux</strong> du Domaine</div>
        [products_slider cats="25" slide_to_show="5" design="design-5" dots="false" slide_to_scroll="2"]
      </li>
    </ul>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: make sure your `document.getElementById` where you use `.setAttribute` on the result are actually getting an element - chances are, you're running `for(var j = 0; j < 5; j ++){` BEFORE the document has loaded and the elements exist - try moving that loop inside the `jQuery(document).ready(function($) {` callback

Comment: You should check if element exists first. 
Something like `var element = document.getElementById('someId');` and `(element) && element.setAttribute('style','something');`

Comment: Hi, welcome to stack overflow. It is very valuable if you know how to debug a program to 
investigate the current program state. Start using the F12 tools in the browser you use for example.

Comment: Thank you for answering!I've added jQuery(document).ready(function($) {...} before the doc has loaded, it doesn't work.

Comment: the element exists but the problem is that the buttons and sliders are working for the screens up to the width of 1600

Comment: I've noticed that product's slider is working for devices <1600px if I change the theme  to another one.  But the problem is that I should use the theme where slider doesn't work.